# Obtener valor de un atributo con laravel

Tags: laravel

Buenas estoy trabajando con laravel queria preguntar si hay alguna forma de preguntar el valor de un atributo de un registro en una etiqueta de html? El valor que quiero obtener es el enable de la tabla categories pero que a traves de product. 
esta etiqueta tiene un if pero como puedo implementarlo en mi caso:

```
<select class="form-control" name="category_id">

<option value="0">General</option>
@foreach ($categories as $category)
<option value=" {{ $category->id }} " @if($category->id==
old('category_id', $product->category_id)) selected @endif>

{{ $category->name }}

</option>
@endforeach
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

En el curso vi que la etiqueta tenia la siguiente forma:

```
@foreach($products as $product)
      <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="team-player">
              <img src="{{ $product->images()->first()->image }}" alt="Thumbnail Image" class="img-raised rounded-circle">
              <h4 class="title">
                  <a href="{{ url('/products/'.$product->id) }}">  {{ $product->name }} </a>
                  <br>
                **<small class="card-description text-muted"> {{ $product->category_name }} </small>**
              </h4>
              <div class="card-body">
                  <p class="card-description">{{ $product->description }}</p>
              </div>
              <div class="card-footer justify-content-center">

              </div>
          </div>
       </div>
@endforeach
```

Solo la etiqueta `small` es lo que me interesa que vean:

y en el archivo donde el `product` (creo que es la entidad) había un método para devolver un mensaje pero solo si están ausentes físicamente los registros, no logicamente.

```
public function getCategoryNameAttrbitute()
{
    if ( $this->category )

        return $this->category->name;

    return 'Sin Categoria Asignada';

}
```

Intenté modificar el modificar el `if` para que quedara así:

```
if ( $this->category->enable==1 )

        return $this->category->name;

    return 'Sin Categoria Asignada';
```

Pero no funciona, me devuelve un espacio en blanco en donde debería ir el mensaje.

Comment: ¿Por qué obtenerlo a través de product si el foreach está hecho en la categoría? En mi opinión se puede obtener directamente sin pasar por la relación.

Comment: no, te explico, la etiqueta que envie es un ejemplo la utilizo en otro formulario, lo que necesito es obtener el nombre de la categoria pero que tenga el enable en true o 1, a traves del producto por que es en el formulario donde aparecen los datos del producto

Answer (score 0):

Si ya tengo el producto, y si la relación entre los dos modelos está correctamente definida según los lineamientos de Eloquent, puedo llamar a la categoría como una propiedad del producto, y posteriormente sus propiedades:

```
// obtengo el producto con su relación de categoría, usando Eager Loading
$product = Product::with('category')
           ->whereId($id)
           ->first();

// obtengo el nombre de la categoría relacionada con dicho producto
echo $product->category->name;

// obtengo el atributo enable de la categoría
echo $product->category->enable
```

Todo esto lo encuentras en la documentación de Laravel/Eloquent:

- https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships
- https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading